# C# validating a XML with a XSD

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-code, xsd, xsd-validation

I am new at C# and I am trying to create an .exe using C# and Visual Studio Code (VSC).
The .exe shall receive two arguments that are the complete paths for the xsd and xml files.

Example:

- xpto.exe "C:\Users\dpaiva\Desktop\catalog.xml" "D:\catalog.xsd"

I was adapting a code that I found, because this is not a new "problem" in IT or C#.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    if (args == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("source");
    } else {
    var xsdfile = "";
    var xmlfile = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++){
        if (i==0){
            xsdfile = args[i];
        } else if (i==1){
            xmlfile = args[i];
        }
    }
    XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
    if (xsdfile != null){
        schema.Add("", xsdfile);
    } 
    XmlReader rd = XmlReader.Create(xmlfile);  
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(rd);  
    doc.Validate(schema, ValidationEventHandler);  
    }  
    static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) {  
    XmlSeverityType type = XmlSeverityType.Warning;  
        if (Enum.TryParse < XmlSeverityType > ("Error", out type)) {  
        if (type == XmlSeverityType.Error) throw new Exception(e.Message);  
        }  
    }
}
```

When I am debbuging the code in VSC and it is being displayed the following error:
Line 37: schema.Add("", xsdfile);

System.ArgumentNullException in System.Private.Xml.dll: 'Value cannot be null'.

Since I have to low experience with C#, I don't know how to fix this problem and if my code it is correctly to handle the urls.

Can anyone help me to try to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you're looking for, good luck.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace xmlutil {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            string strFileName = String.Empty;

            try {

                if (args.Length < 2) {
                    throw new Exception("Usage: xmlutil.exe [file.xml|folder\\*.xml] file.xsd");
                }

                System.IO.FileAttributes attr = System.IO.File.GetAttributes( args[0] );

                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

                strFileName = args[1]; // to detect errors in the schema

                settings.Schemas.Add(null, args[1]);
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                settings.ValidationFlags =
                                XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |
                                XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
                                XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema |
                                XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;


                if (attr.HasFlag(System.IO.FileAttributes.Directory)) {

                    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(args[0]);




                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(args[0], "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    int i = files.Length;
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing folder " + args[0] + " - " + i + " files.");

                    int nTen = Convert.ToInt32(files.Length / 10);
                    int nCount = 0;

                    for (i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
                        strFileName = files[i];
                        try {
                            ValidateFile(files[i], settings);

                            if ((i % nTen) == 0) {
                                if (nCount > 0) {
                                    Console.WriteLine(nCount * 10 + "% complete.");
                                }
                                nCount++;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex2) {
                            Console.Error.WriteLine(strFileName);
                            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex2.Message);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    strFileName = args[0];
                    ValidateFile(args[0], settings);
                }
            } catch (XmlSchemaException exs) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(strFileName + " schema validation exeption" );
                Console.Error.WriteLine(exs.Message + " Line: " + exs.LineNumber + " Column: " + exs.LinePosition );
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(strFileName);
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }

        static void ValidateFile(string strXMLFile, XmlReaderSettings settings) {

            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strXMLFile, settings);
            document.Load(reader);
            // the following call to Validate succeeds.
            document.Validate(eventHandler);
        }

        static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) {
            switch (e.Severity) {
                case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
                    break;
                case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                    Console.WriteLine("Warning {0}", e.Message);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
However this have more functionalities that I need.
I dont need to get all the xml files in a directory, the argument will be a path with the xml to be validate and the other will be the path with the xsd to do the match.
I also dont need the counter because it is only to validate one xml file against one xsd file.

I am trying to adapt the code sent by you however I am getting some issues to do that without breaking it

Comment: BTW, the program works with either a folder of XML files, or a single XML file.